# trouble converting check_box_tag to f.check_box - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I need to convert check_box_tag to f.check_box, but I am having trouble doing so.

My check box has

```
check_box_tag 'privacy', 1, (@idea.privacy=='private'), :id=>"Make Private"
```

So the name = 'privacy', value = 1, checked when (@idea.privacy=='private') is true, and has id "Make Private".  Can anyone help me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add a virtual attribute to do this.

For example, in `app/models/idea.rb`:

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :is_private

  def is_private
    privacy == 'private'
  end

  def is_private=(true_or_false)
    self.privacy = true_or_false ? 'private' : 'public'
  end
end
```

It can be used in a form like this:

```
<%= form_for(@idea) do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :is_private %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I suggest following the convention of Rails and use the generated id of the checkbox: `idea_is_private`.

If you intend to name it in different way, here is how you can do it:

```
<%= f.check_box :is_private, :id => 'make-private' %>
```

p.s. Most people do not use spaces in ids.

p.s.s. How the virtual attribute works:

`f.check_box :is_private` informs Rails of which methods should be used to read and write to the record. In this case, the value of the checkbox would be `@idea.is_private`. And, when the checobox is checked, code like `@idea.is_private = true` gets executed.

To make that works, we have to add the `is_private` and `is_private=(true_or_false)` methods in the model.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  can you explain to me what is going on in the model?  Thanks!

Comment: @BooBailey Since the explanation is somewhat long, I have updated it to the end of the answer. Please take a look. :)